# Constexpr static member function usage

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, static-methods, constexpr

Consider the following example code:

```
#include <array>

struct MyClass
{
  size_t value = 0;

  constexpr static size_t size() noexcept
  {
    return 3;
  }
};

template <size_t N>
void DoIt()
{
  MyClass h;
  std::array<int, h.size()> arr;
}

int main()
{
  DoIt<1>();
}
```

When I try to compile this with GCC 7.3.0, I get an error about h not being usable in a non-constexpr context:

```
cexpr.cpp: In function ‘void DoIt()’:
cexpr.cpp:17:26: error: the value of ‘h’ is not usable in a constant expression
   std::array<int, h.size()> arr;
                          ^
cexpr.cpp:16:11: note: ‘h’ was not declared ‘constexpr’
   MyClass h;
           ^
cexpr.cpp:17:27: error: the value of ‘h’ is not usable in a constant expression
   std::array<int, h.size()> arr;
                           ^
cexpr.cpp:16:11: note: ‘h’ was not declared ‘constexpr’
   MyClass h;
           ^
```

However, when I try compiling the exact same code in Clang 6.0.0, it compiles without any errors. Additionally, when I modify the code to not be inside the templated `DoIt()` function, GCC compiles this just fine:

```
#include <array>

struct MyClass
{
  size_t value = 0;

  constexpr static size_t size() noexcept
  {
    return 3;
  }
};

int main()
{
  MyClass h;
  // this compiles just fine in Clang and GCC
  std::array<int, h.size()> arr;
}
```

I already know how to fix the first code so it compiles on GCC using `decltype`, but I'm curious to know why doesn't the first piece of code compile with GCC? Is this just a bug in GCC, or is there something I don't understand about using constexpr static member functions?

Comment: Why not `MyClass::size()`?

Comment: That's effectively the fix I had where I used `decltype(h)::size()`. I don't name MyClass specifically since this piece of code was isolated from a much larger templated code where spelling out the type is rather cumbersome and prone to breakage if the type declaration changes.

Comment: I am mostly curious why using `h.size()` doesn't work, since as far as I know it's supposed to have identical semantic rules, unless there's some nuance I'm missing.

Comment: @helloworld922: See a similar bug report on GCC. [`constexpr` member function calls in a `constexpr` constructor are ignored if the object is defined locally](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80039)

Comment: @P.W that's an interesting bug, though one difference I can see is that I'm not modifying anything in my constexpr functions. I don't know enough about the design of GCC to know if the two issues are caused by the same bug. That does give me hope that this is a GCC bug and not a gap in my understanding of C++, though.

Comment: You could make an argument that, since the left-hand-side of a binary `.` expression still needs to be evaluated as an expression before it gets resolved (like, I could do `(MyClass{} + MyClass{}).size()` if MyClass had a `operator+()`. The fact that the `h` expression has no side-effects is something that could get collapsed fairly late during the compilation process, so it's not entirely unreasonable to require it to be `constexpr`.

Comment: @Frank If that were the case, I don't understand why when I use h.size() in the context of a template function it fails to compile, but in the context of a non-templated function it compiles just fine.

Comment: There’s some uncertainty among implementors/experts as to whether a call to a static member function via a non-`constexpr` object is a constant expression.  You’re not supposed to be able to use such a variable in a constant expression, but the static member function of course doesn’t really use it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Is the bounty even for confirming this as a bug?

Comment: @P.W If confirming means providing a standard reference, then yes.

Comment: I think that it's fair to say there is at least one bug or inconsistency present in GCC. In templated functions, it says `h.size()` is not constexpr because `h` can't be constexpr. However, in non-templated functions GCC now says that `h.size()` is constexpr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me.

The type and meaning of the expression `h.size()` is defined by `[expr.ref]` "Class member access":

> #### [`[expr.post]/3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#expr.ref-3.sentence-1)
>
> Abbreviating *postfix-expression.id-expression* as `E1.E2`, `E1` is called the object expression. [...]

and

> #### [`[expr.post]/6.3.1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#expr.ref-6.3.1)
>
> If `E2` is a (possibly overloaded) member function, function overload resolution is used to determine whether `E1.E2` refers to a static or a non-static member function.
>
> - (6.3.1) If it refers to a static member function and the type of `E2` is “function of parameter-type-list returning `T`”, then `E1.E2` is an lvalue; **the expression designates the static member function**. The type of `E1.E2` is the same type as that of `E2`, namely “function of parameter-type-list returning `T`”.

This means `h.size` has the same type as `::MyClass::size` and is evaluated as such, **regardless of the fact that `h` is `constexpr` or not**.

`h.size()` is then a call to a `constexpr` function and is a *core constant expression* according to [`[expr.const]/4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4).

Comment: Funny enough, `MyClass h; std::array<int, h.size()> arr;` is rejected by gcc trunk, but `std::array<int, MyClass{}.size()> arr;` is accepted: https://godbolt.org/z/GtStLT

Comment: FYI, in gcc-7.3, this is the fact that `std::array` has non-static data members which triggers the bug. Look: https://godbolt.org/z/Cz38hS